# Unable to run test on real device but running on simulator

Tags: webdriver, appium, appium-ios

As I am new to real-time device testing, I need your support in resolving an issue which I am facing since long now. I have following issues with iOS devices and simulators:

1. I am able to run my script in the simulator but not on the real-time device.
2. Unable to see WebDriverAgentRunner app on the device, however, I have built that app multiple times.
3. My Scrip is able to interact with Appium, it gets installed also but never gets open (In Eclipse it gets failed with error: No element found)

Please find the attached appium logs and desired capabilities below:
        Desired Capabilities:

```
IOSDriver wd = null;
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    System.out.println("     ");
    capabilities.setCapability("appium-version", "1.7.2");
    capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "XCUITest");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
    capabilities.setCapability("udid", “UDID”); //6Plus
    //capabilities.setCapability("noReset", "true");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "11.2.6"); 
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone 6”); 
    capabilities.setCapability("app",
            “<Path of builded Application.app>”); 

    capabilities.setCapability("bundleID", “<com.bundel id>”);
    wd = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), 
    capabilities);
```

Also in the simulator, I am able to run only on one device.

[Appium Logs Are present in this link](https://gist.github.com/siddtiwari/9f98b74ec775c823ecdb4712a16bd141)

Comment: hi, are you using the same .ipa file for real device, which you are using to launch the application on simulator ?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer Thanks for the update.. I will keep that in mind

Comment: @SurajJogdand I have the same .ipa file. I build the project in Xcode for simulator and then I have build the same project on Real time device also. Then the path to .APP file is what I am using

Comment: From the log, I see error "Error: An attempt was made to operate on a modal dialog when one was not open." Seems like the app is launched on device?

Comment: "bundleId" not "bundleID". I guess that should fix

Comment: @Srikanth , I have tried with "bundleId" but not working. WebDriverAgentRunner app gets installed but never gets open.

Comment: @Srikanth , I have tried with "bundleId" but not working. WebDriverAgentRunner app gets installed but never gets open.

Comment: Can you post the new log again after changing to bundleId